# Google Script Error (no permission)

Tags: google-apps-script

This very simple ClearCell() script shown below works just fine when run from the script editor, but when called from the spreadsheet with

```
=IF(C1<>"",ClearCell(),)
```

I get **YOU DO NOT HAVE PERMISSION TO CALL CLEAR CONTENT (LINE 3)**

```
function ClearCell() {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.getRange('B1').clearContent();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The permissions for custom functions are different than the regular Apps Script code permissions.  When using the `Spreadsheet` service, which includes `SpreadsheetApp`, it is "Read Only".  The `clearContent()` method is not "read only".  It's changing data in the sheet.  So even though it's not a "set" method, it's still not "Read Only".

This behavior is described in the documentation at the following link:

[Google Documentation - Using Apps Script Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#using_apps_script_services)

You will probably need to use either a simple `onEdit(e)` function, or an installable "On Change" function.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) :

> A custom function cannot affect cells other than those it returns a
> value to. In other words, a custom function cannot edit arbitrary
> cells, only the cells it is called from and their adjacent cells. To
> edit arbitrary cells, use a custom menu to run a function instead.

you are trying to clear a cell that is not the one containing the function.